# concatenations in facebook meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

while I am using the facebook  og:image meta tag , when I put

```
  <meta property="og:image"   content="<?=$config['SITE_URL'].'Images/Items/Thumbnails/thumb_Item24.jpg'?>" />
```

the object debugger accepts and finds the image , but when i put it like this:

```
<meta property="og:image"   content="<?=$config['SITE_URL'].'Images/Items/Thumbnails/thumb_'.$itemImage?>"/>
```

where $itemImage is Item24.jpg , object debugger doesn't recognize it. why ? anything wrong with the concatination ??

and another thing.

can I put a meta tag in an if clause? like

```
 <?if(case A) { 
       <meta property="og:image"   content="ImageA">
  }else{
       <meta property="og:image"   content="ImageB">
  }
```

because when I am doing that, it is always taking image B although condition A is true.

Answer (score 0):

Are you clearing Facebook's cache of your page after you change the meta tags? The meta tags for a URL shouldn't change very often, the cache is only cleared once every 24 hours or so unless you use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clear it manually

Comment: i am testing the page through Facebook's debug tool, so yes cache is cleared.

Comment: And which tags are you serving to Facebook's debugger? If you don't trust the debugger, check manually with in a terminal with curl: `curl -i -H '\''Accept: */*'\'' -H '\''Range: bytes=0-40960'\'' -H '\''Connection: close'\'' -A '\''facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'\''' <URL HERE>` will replicate the same request Facebook makes

Comment: i am sure it is cleared because when i try different cases the image in the debugger is changing. nothing is stuck.. so you r saying you can't see anything wrong in the concatenation? and what about my second question.anything wrong with this condition? i am a beginner in all these stuff.

Comment: _„so you r saying you can't see anything wrong in the concatenation?”_ – so _you’re_ saying you haven’t checked this yourself before even asking here by simply having a look into the HTML code your script generates …?